# SSH failing after Postponed publickey and single attempt

Tags: bash, perl, ssh, public-key, sshd

I have a working SSH setup that uses publickey without any issues. Specifically, I'm using SCP -i to copy files to a remote server and it works

```
scp -i /var/www/key/id_rsa /var/www/backups/example.dat living@example.com:/var/www/backups
```

This works fine as a command line when logged in as **root** or **living**.

Here is an example of **WORKING** debug from a /usr/sbin/sshd -d test:

```
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from X.X.X.X port 33166 on Y.Y.Y.Y port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: SELinux support disabled [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16 [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user living service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "living"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "FQDN_redacted"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user living service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1001/1001 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/living/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Found matching RSA key: 5a:c2:98:38:bf:b3:01:13:55:b0:3d:74:61:3f:b1:f3
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for living from X.X.X.X port 33166 ssh2 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user living service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1001/1001 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/living/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Found matching RSA key: 5a:c2:98:38:bf:b3:01:13:55:b0:3d:74:61:3f:b1:f3
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted publickey for living from X.X.X.X port 33166 ssh2: RSA 5a:c2:98:38:bf:b3:01:13:55:b0:3d:74:61:3f:b1:f3
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: living has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1001/1001 (e=0/0)
debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
User child is on pid 2320
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1001/1001
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
```

My problem is this: when I run the **same** SCP command within a PERL script, as a backtick bash command, it fails with the following debug.

```
$x=`scp -i /var/www/keys/living/id_rsa /var/www/$RS->[$x][3].dat living\@$a:/var/www/`;
```

I'm thinking the issue might be resolved if I can figure out why the SCP command run inside PERL is only trying once.

Here is an example of **FAILING** debug from a /usr/sbin/sshd -d test:

```
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from X.X.X.X port 33208 on Y.Y.Y.Y port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: SELinux support disabled [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16 [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user living service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "living"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "FQDN_redacted"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user living service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1001/1001 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/living/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Found matching RSA key: 5a:c2:98:38:bf:b3:01:13:55:b0:3d:74:61:3f:b1:f3
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for living from X.X.X.X port 33208 ssh2 [preauth]
Connection closed by X.X.X.X [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 2409
```

Comment: What does your script look like? My money would be on an interpolation/escaping/quoting problem.

Comment: $x=`scp -i /var/www/keys/living/id_rsa /var/www/$RS->[$x][3].dat living\@$a:/var/www/`;

Comment: Please edit that into your post.

Comment: Added to post above second debug.

Comment: It might be relevant to add that this backtick SCP command was working correctly in the script. The only thing that has fundamentally changed is that it now runs as part of a child process that is fork'ed from the parent with $|=1; and $SIG{CHLD} = "IGNORE"; set (because I need the parent to exit for user browser update reasons).

Comment: After further thought, I shifted the code from the child fork back into the main code, and ... I'm embarrassed to say... I got the dread error_log entry: "Permissions 0660 for ... too open". Will do further testing and come back with results. :(

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was that the permissions of the file "**id_rsa**" private key was set to **0660** and had to be changed to **0600**.

A noob error that was obscured because the SCP command was being run within PERL
*backticks* as the child of a PERL fork with these commands:

```
 $|=1;$SIG{CHLD} = "IGNORE";
```

This causes debug from the child process to not show up in the Apache error_log, and no amount of debug was exposing the issue on either the source or destination servers.